# Laravel Log channel undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am at a loss, I can't find anyone else having this issue so it feels like I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot figure it out.  When I attempt to log to a specific channel in Laravel ([Reference Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#writing-log-messages)) using

```
Log::channel('a channel')->info('a message');
```

I get:

```
PHP Error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate/Log/Writer::channel()
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you got the import wrong.

Did you try importing `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a dufus.  I THOUGHT I had upgraded to 5.6, but I didn't actually save the composer file before I ran the update :/

ACTUALLY Upgraded to 5.6 and no longer getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
$logger = new Logger('channel-name');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/app.log', Logger::DEBUG));
$logger->info('This is a log! ^_^ ');
$logger->warning('This is a log warning! ^_^ ');
$logger->error('This is a log error! ^_^ ');
```

this is worked for me in laravel.